# Postresql, Node.js ORM - foreignKey and primaryKey issue in relation table (Many to Many)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, orm, sequelize.js

I am just creating `Company` and `Industry` table in many-to-many relation.
A company can contain multiple industries and one industry can contain multiple countries.
In UI, like multi-select box for company where I can choose several industries.

What I am doing in models:

Industry.js

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Industry = sequelize.define('Industry', {
    industry_name: DataTypes.STRING,
  }, {
    timestamps: false,
    underscored: true,
    tableName: 'industry',
  });
  Industry.associate = function(models) {
    Industry.belongsToMany(models.Company, {
      through: 'company_industry_relation', foreignkey: 'industry_id'
    });
  };
  return Industry;
};
```

Company.js

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Company = sequelize.define('Company', {
    company_name: DataTypes.STRING,
  }, {
    timestamps: false,
    underscored: true,
    tableName: 'company',
  });
  Company.associate = function(models) {
    Company.belongsToMany(models.Industry, {
      through: 'company_industry_relation', foreignKey: 'company_id'
    });
  };
  return Company;
};
```

CompanyIndustryRelation.js

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const CompanyIndustryRelation = sequelize.define('CompanyIndustryRelation', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
  }, {
    timestamps: false,
    underscored: true,
    tableName: 'company_industry_relation',
  });
  CompanyIndustryRelation.associate = function(models) {
    CompanyIndustryRelation.belongsTo(models.Company, { foreignKey: 'company_id' });
    CompanyIndustryRelation.belongsTo(models.Industry, { foreignKey: 'industry_id' });
  };
  return CompanyIndustryRelation;
};
```

But what I am concerned here is those models are creating company_id(PK) and industry_id(PK) in `company_industry_relation` table.
Also id(PK) is not created in the table.
In my opinion those two columns (company_id and industry_id) should be foreign keys and id(PK) should be created differing to those two columns?

Could anyone have an idea about this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need the associations in your relation table... just remove them... setting up either side of the belongsToMany is enough...

Your primary key in the relation table is a compound primary key... that means a company can belong to many industries, and a industry may have many companies but you can never duplicate the compound primary key...

```
company_id         industry_id
1                  1
1                  2
2                  2
2                  3
```

These are all valid records in your join table, and the combination of them make up the primary key of the record... so obviously once 1,1 is used, then you can't nor would you want to add it again type thing... if you included an actual id field in that primary key then you or someone else working in your code could accidentally add that same relation again

Comment: Thank you for replying, Greg! Actually, at first, I have ever tried without the relational model definition. But it was the same as it is currently. I think it's not a big deal if I define the relational model or I don't.

Comment: removed and executed but those two columns (company_id, undustry_id) are still `PK` in the relational table. I am sure those should be foreginKey, why two primarKeys are being created in the relational table? Is it normal?

Comment: yes, it's a compound primary key... it's fine... you don't even really need an id field on that table because just those two fields would be enough... You will never be able to duplicate an entry with those two fields as primary key, but technically you could by accident if you involve all three.. personally i would remove the id field all together

Comment: i can't imagine a scenario where having the id field is a plus for you since you don't store any other data you would want to manage in there

Comment: Thanks for updating, Greg. I updated code as you suggested above but the same as those are PK, also id in the relational table is not being created. :(

Comment: Actually, id is not a big deal, but what I am concerning is why the two relational keys are not Foreign Keys but PK?

Comment: They are foreign keys, but not in the relational table itself... they are the primary key of relational table... the foreign key relation is in the company table itself and industry table... company_id is the foreign key to the company table.... but in the relational table together they make up the primary key.... maybe you just need to read up a bit on that... it is working as it should

Comment: if you open pgadmin and select your company table and hit CREATE script or Properties it will show you the FK relation in there if you are concerned it does not exist properly...

Comment: Company_id matches with id in company table, that's why I think it's primary key in company table but it should be a foreign key in the company_industry_relation table.
Simply, thinking, I can not have duplicated value as primary key in the relational table, but I can have the duplicated company_id in the relational tabl because several companies have one industry.

Comment: it's a compound primary key though... that means both fields make up the primary key, so you can have many of the same company_id's in there and many of the same industry_id's but no record can have both id's the same

Comment: industry_id = 1 could have 10 associated country_id's for instance in that relation table.... 1,1, 1,2, 1,3 etc, are all acceptable records.  does not mean you can not ever duplicate one or the other, just can't duplicate both, and nor would you ever want to

Comment: yes, exactly. That's why I want to know. I think those are foreign keys and primary keys concurrently. I have never seen this kind of situation. Now clear. 
Could you update the answer with those? I can give you acceptance.

Comment: Greg, one thing quickly. Creating the relational model is mandatory?
That's why I can see the relational table created without defining the model in Postgresql DB.
Only `through` definition in both of the original tables are automatically creating the relational table, no?

Comment: i updated the answer, and that is correct... about what constitutes the relation.. you are all good